# Is there a complete list of evolution costs?

Tags: pokemon-go

For pokemon that evolve twice I like to wait until I have enough candy to do both evolutions at once. Problem is I can't find the cost of the second evolution.

Is there a list of evolution costs anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From personal experience, the first evolution of a Pokémon that has 2 evolutions costs 25 candy, and the second evolution costs 100 candy, though there are 3 exceptions; Weedle, Caterpie, and Pidgey which cost 12 and 50 candy for first and second evolutions respectively. For Pokémon with only one evolution, the cost to evolve is 50 candy, except for Magikarp who costs 400 candy to evolve, and Eevee and Rattata who cost 25 to evolve.

Based on the [link](http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/evolution.shtml) @MatthewCargille provided, these are all of the different evolution costs.

Comment: Pidgeotto also seems to be an exception, as its second evolution costs 50.

Comment: @freekvd, idk how I missed that one, I have evolved Pidgeotto's like 7 times already for the xp.

Comment: There are also a couple exceptions which require 25 candy to evolve but only have one evolution: Rattata and Eevee.